# Pizza delivery app photos wont render to application

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

Im trying to create a Pizza delivery app with React and next.js. What I'm stuck with is the photos of the pizzas I have in the sanity backend won't render to the app. I can see the json array for the 6 pizzas in the terminal and also the console after i connect the backend. I've been stuck on this all day and appreciate any help. Is there a different way to pass pizzas to the Home function in the index.js? :)
The exact error is below aswell.

```
error - components\Menu.jsx (17:27) @ eval
TypeError: (0 , _lib_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default) is not a function
  15 |       {/* pizzas */}
  16 |       {pizzas.map((pizza, id) => {
> 17 |         const src = urlFor(pizza.image);
     |                           ^
  18 |         console.log(pizza.image);
  19 |         return (
  20 |           <div className={css.pizza} key={id}>
```

**Index.js**

```
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import Hero from '../components/Hero';
import css from '../styles/Home.module.css';
import Services from '../components/Services';
import { client } from '../lib/client';
import Menu from '../components/Menu';

export default function Home({ pizzas }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={css.container}>
        <Head>
          <title>FUDO</title>
          <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
          <link rel="icon" href="/Logo.png" />
        </Head>
        {/* body */}
        <main>
          <Hero />
          <Services />
          <Menu pizzas={pizzas} />
        </main>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const query = '*[_type == "pizza"]';
  const pizzas = await client.fetch(query);
  console.log(pizzas);
  return {
    props: {
      pizzas,
    },
  };
};
```

**Menu.jsx**

```
import urlFor from '../lib/client';
import Image from 'next/image';

export default function Menu({ pizzas }) {
  console.log(pizzas);
  return (
    <div className={css.container}>
      <div className={css.heading}>
        <span>OUR MENU</span>
        <span>Menu That Always</span>
        <span>Make You Fall In Love</span>
      </div>

      {/* pizzas */}
      {pizzas.map((pizza, id) => {
        const src = urlFor(pizza.image);
        console.log(pizza.image);
        return (
          <div className={css.pizza} key={id}>
            <div className={css.ImageWrapper}>
              <Image
                loader={() => src}
                src={src}
                alt=""
                objectFit="cover"
                layout="fill"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Client.js**

```
import SanityClient from '@sanity/client';
import ImageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = SanityClient({
  projectId: 'exiz0rgv',
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2022-09-01',
  useCdn: true,
  token:
    'skT82oCId91vDPWOQoLVx6qVxX3mLxGYzSQeX0tsRRS2KGDFtmWXuIRxz0yyz3RyErMeUHraDpTDTLbWgjoiLcnh4GoL3CChOcNpkGFzQeywcAR73yQiqnxjBlL3Z435QgzTZJEEZJnI7O0R4RdQaCivBTKKIBV79efdtavbNvcfx9iSB2nS',
});

const builder = ImageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is the smallest amount of code to understand my problem? I need the client.js because that is my backend where i have the images I'm trying to server side render. I need the menu.js because that's I'm putting the images and I'm passing it to my index.js so its on the app UI. I'm confused what's wrong. This always happens on this site.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is in the pizzas part of the menu.js. I can console.log all the json but when i console.log pizza.image i get nothing in the menu.js. the images are not fetching properly from the backend.

Comment: Can anyone help me with why no one replies to my posts on this site. I have had this post viewed 30 times and not 1 person has left a comment? appreciate the help and support :)

Comment: You're exporting `urlFor` as a named export, but importing it from the default export in `Menu`. Change the import in the `Menu` component to `import { urlFor } from '../lib/client';`.

Comment: @juloimalves Thank you i will fix that up now and continue on. Thank you for your help

Comment: hey @juliomalves Do you have discord I have a error I've been struggling with all day. Stackoverflow doesn't let me create another post until tomorrow sadly? :)